# Excel #Num when working with negative Powers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell that evaluates `POWER(-0.230819,-0.999998)` into #NUM and I need it to output the actual answer:`-4.33238627566`

Simplifying down the error I see excel also cannot do `POWER(-0.2,-0.4)`

I thought that these were relatively straightforward calculations, how can I fix this?

I have already tried enabling iterative calculation in excel settings but that didn't help.

Comment: Thankyou Olly you legend. Feel free to write this as an answer and I will accept it for you. Also, why does everyone comment the answer rather than answering now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an Excel issue - See [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180114135902/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62979.html)

Of course, you could approximate by using

```
=-POWER(0.230819,-0.999998)
```